# Getting Status Code: 400 while trying too consume message from AWS sqs using apache camel

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Here is the camel configuration used :

```
from("aws-sqs://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/350349789562/notification_queue?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient")
```

I do have the required permissions in place for `AWS` `SQS` but getting invalid parameters error from `SQS`

> org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1:
>   Route(route1)[[From[aws-sqs://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   aws-sqs://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/350349789562/notification_queue?amazonSQSClient=%23sqsClient
>   due to: Can only include alphanumeric characters, hyphens, or
>   underscores. 1 to 80 in length (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
>   78483b78-a847-50e0-803d-6926743498cf)
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uri format should be aws-sqs://queueName[?options]. Find more details [here](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html)

In your case it would be

```
aws-sqs://notification_queue?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient
```

Rest of the details are to be provided as options. Probably as

```
queueOwnerAWSAccountId=350349789562&region=ap-south-1
```